# SplitView in Rows in QML

Tags: qml, splitter, qsplitter

A qml having many rowlayouts, I want to add splitter between the rowlayouts in QML

Rowlayout{

}

Rowlayout{

}

//Add splitter between these two rows

Comment: Can't you use a `Rectangle`?

Comment: No @smr . I need SplitView between charts and rowlayouts

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: have a Look at the SplitView example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html#details. Basically you suround your items with the SplitView.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure:

1. Your `SplitView` is appropriately positioned/sized (e.g. `anchors.fill: parent`)
2. At least one of your `SplitView` children has a non-zero size (e.g. `SplitView.preferredWidth: 100`)

```
    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        RowLayout { 
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 100
        }
        RowLayout { 
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABJnichY3BDoJADETv+xUNH0DwytUriaJGzysUbVy3m1KChuy/i9GQgAfnNtPpG7oHFoVSy46qm6GZTdfsVdi1y7ywT+60NVt7QRgMjNoHR3ok7L/+LeurK0ubNuRcDsEKep2OO+4/GBhgCmekNAg2KIL1iWq95rDKslmzsGd047viQ3NINh4TiFMj/p9aAA49/wKiieYFo2dTFw==)